# Selenium unable to click on the webelement element ( file upload button)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");
      driver.findElement(By.linkText("log in")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.google.openid_large_btn")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("username@gmail.com");
      driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("password");
      driver.findElement(By.id("hlinks-user")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.linkText("user2131252")).click();
      Thread.sleep(3000L);

      // None of these work to click on the upload button , actions, robot..
  //driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='change-picture']")).click();
      //Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
      //WebElement changepic = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='change-picture']"));
      //actions.moveToElement(changepic).click().perform();
      //actions.click();
      //actions.perform();

      /*Point coordinates = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='change-picture']")).getLocation();
      Robot robot = new Robot();
      robot.mouseMove(coordinates.getX(),coordinates.getY()+120);
      //robot.mousePress(coordinates.getX());
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='change-picture']")).clear();
      */

      Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    //for hovering over the username field
    WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='change- picture']"));
    actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
    //for clicking the logout link
    WebElement logoutLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='change-picture']"));
    logoutLink.click();
```

Please I am unable to click on the change-picture link, I get different errors on different browsers.

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Element cannot be scrolled into view: (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 13 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.33.0', revision: '4e90c97', time: '2013-05-22 15:33:32'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_17'
Session ID: 4534c06c-0622-4610-8d7d-1cf99f9577ee
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=24.0}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteExecuteMethod.execute(RemoteExecuteMethod.java:34)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteMouse.mouseMove(RemoteMouse.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveMouseAction.perform(MoveMouseAction.java:36)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.CompositeAction.perform(CompositeAction.java:31)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.perform(Actions.java:356)
    at test.stackoverflow.main(stackoverflow.java:52)

Comment: I am unable to click on the 'change-picture' button which inturn brings up the fileupload. All I am trying to do is to upload a picture on my profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using `javascriptExcecuter` after sleep(),

```
 ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('#change-picture').click();");
```

Comment: above line works on chrome, but on firefox I get an error message. Any thoughts on it?

Comment: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: waiting for evaluate.js load failed

Comment: Updating to latest Webdriver  solves the firefox issue. Thank you